# Почему var_dump NULL?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, переменные, foreach

(Несколько **button** выводятся в цикле **foreach**) ALERT работает и выводит у каждой кнопки свой id. Весь приведённый код выполняется в одном файле. **Почему переменная $ids пустая?**

```
<button onclick="addInCart(<?=$key['id']?>)">Купить +</button>

<script>
function addInCart(id){
         $.ajax({
              type:'post',
              url:'',
              data:{'add_id': id},
              success:function(data){
                   alert(id);  
              }

         });
     }
</script>
<?php
$ids = $_POST['add_id'];
var_dump($ids); //NULL
?>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А где вы проверяете вывод var_dump? Он у вас по идее в data у success

Comment: @ARTISUC переменная пустая, на сервер ниче не отправляется

Answer (score 3):

$ids пустая из за пустого $_POST['add_id'];
Массив $_POST пустой из-за того что при переходе на страницу браузер отправляет get а не post запрос.
В вашем случае $_POST получит параметры только после того как будет отправлен AJAX запрос на сервер, результат работы можно посмотреть в панели разработчика на вкладке Network (XHR) запросы

Comment: Прикольная ава)))

Comment: Как так GET если в функции аякс указан POST? Подскажите как правильно написать пожалуйста.

Comment: Добавил скрин в вопрос, переменную на скрине вывожу уже через var_dump($ids); В Network (XHR) выводит при клике string(2) "28", а наскрине в углу NULL. В чём дело то может быть? И кто тут такой умник мне репу заминусовал?... лучше бы подсказку кинули.

Comment: @ARTISUC Вам уже всё объяснили. На странице показывается NULL потому что Вы когда обновляете её, или просто заходите на неё то ничего никуда не отправляете, соответственно, $_POST пуст, а ajax это уже другой запрос, отличный от вашей страницы, там вы отправляете запрос. Чтобы выводилось на странице вам надо добавить форму с методом post и при клике отправлять её, тогда страница будет обновляться и будет показываться ваш var_dump

Comment: А без формы это нельзя сделать никак? Недостаточно того, что на кнопке висит событие onclick в аргумент которого передаётся id каждого товара. Если что, это я корзину для товаров пытаюсь сделать.

Comment: @InDevX обернул кнопку в form с методом post = результата нет, тупо обновляется страница

Comment: Господа помогите пожалуйста, я не догоняю как это решить. Может тут найдётся добрый человек, который поможет решить этот вопрос?

Comment: @ARTISUC добавили форму, отлично. Теперь внутри формы добавьте скрытый инпут с `name="add_id"` и туда записывайте айдишник товара в value. Ну и в button добавьте `type="submit"` и уберите ваш onclick. Так всё будет работать. Потом можно переделать на ajax чтоб без обновления всё работало